# Is it better to keep functions in header files or source files

Tags: c++, c

Is it better to keep functions in header files and include them into the main source file, or to keep functions in source files and link them in the main source file?

Some libraries keep functions in their separate source files which are declared in a special header file. When you include that header file in your main source files, you link all of those functions. However, it creates an object files for each of those source files (doesn't it?). I'm thinking wouldn't it be more efficient to keep function in header files that are all included in a special header file?

Including functions

```
#include <foo.h>
#include <boo.h>

int main() {

}
```

Linking functions

```
int foo();
int boo();

int main() {

}
```

Comment: The problem here is that if you ask ten C++ developers "is it better to do <X> or <Y>" you will get eleven different answers.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that you include tags for both `c` and `c++`. In C, if you ask 10 different C developers, you will get 8 different explanations of why you should definitely not put function definitions in a header file, 1 description of nasal demonology, and a treatise on why C++ is an abomination.   In C++, it is common to put definitions in header files.  Which language are you asking about?

Comment: `However, it creates an object files for each of those source files, doesn't it?` No it doesn't, if we are talking about an external library. The linker will pick from the library binary only the symbols it needs. If instead the question is about including or not an header file defined in your project.. well, if you define some function in a different source file it is absolutely ok defining also and header and including it in main file. What if the header file contains dozens of prototypes?

Comment: @WilliamPursell By reading both the comments and the answers I'm not sure I understood the question correctly. Even if it could have been worded better, I see no mention about "defining functions in header files". I would rather say that it is about "including headers" vs. "writing the function prototypes in the head of main file".

Comment: In C++, as long as the developer's time is free and unlimited, it doesn't matter which you do as long as you define those things as inline or constexpr or templates as appropriate to avoid ODR.  If the developer's time is not free or is not unlimited, then optimizing build times might be of interest, in which case putting more things in the header file that could be in a source file is the wrong way to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Header files should not contain any code or data definitions.

In header files:

1. Function prototypes
2. Types declarations (typedefs, structs, unions etc)
3. `extern` objects declarations
4. Macro definitions

and as an exception

5. `static inline` functions definitions.

All other code or object definitions should be in the `.c` source files.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But is there are reason for this? Or is it just a common rule?

Comment: @Wispy see the header file like something the preprocessor _copies_ in place of the `#include` directives in files including them. If you write a function definition (for example `int func(void){return 0;}`) in the header file (full implementation), the file including it will contain this implementation. The problem comes when you include it from more than one file: your linker will complain about `func()` being defined in multiple places.

Comment: @Roberto Caboni, that's why the header have protection from being included more than once like `#pragma once` or `#ifndef FOO_H #define FOO_H ... #endif`

Comment: @Wispy no it is not for that. It is to not load the same more than once in the same **compilation unit**. But if you have a code in .h file and more than one .c file including, it will not help

Comment: @Wispy No. That protection works to avoid to include multiple times the header file from **the same** C file. Each C file, at compiling time, is a different story. In fact at compiling time all will be fine, The erro will come at linking ime.

Answer (score 2):

Practical reasons to use separate source files:

- Real projects can grow to dozens, even hundreds of files - if you’re doing everything with headers, you could wind up with a translation unit that’s too large for the compiler to handle;
- You can’t do incremental builds if everything’s in header files - the smallest change requires a rebuild of the entire project.  I’ve worked on projects that literally took hours to build, so that’s not practical;
- While C doesn’t have a concept of “public” or “private” like C++ or other object-oriented languages, you *can* “hide” function and file scope variable names so that they’re not visible outside the current source file; however, if you include everything as headers, then you lose that ability and everything is visible to everything else;
- Headers can include other headers which can include other headers, etc.  This leads to two problems - duplicate definitions and circular dependencies (A requires B which requires C which requires A).  The former can be dealt with by using include guards, but the second problem tends to be much thornier.

Basically, using separate source files makes code easier to maintain, easier to test, and faster to build.

Answer (score 0):

the declaration of functions inside header files and definition inside separate cpp files help keep your code uncluttered. yes, it will create separate object files for each .h and .cpp file pair but it should't be too big of a deal. in regards to the question, the same thing would happen if you included all the header files inside a main .h file, because it would just compile them one by one and generate object files

Comment: `each .h and .cpp file pair` there in nothing like this. You may include tens of .h files in one .c file.